# sending a text message or email automatically from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to send a text message or email automatically from a chrome extension triggered by an event on a web page? This is for notification within a company, it's not meant to be used by third parties so it's not a privacy issue.

Comment: You'll need to use (or set up) a mail server or an SMS service that exposes an HTTP API that your extension can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way that you could do this (if you have a webserver) is sending the user to a page that is hosted somewhere online, and run a PHP script that emails the user. You would have to use this method because:

- You can't easily use PHP in a chrome extension
- You can't send emails through Javascript/jQuery